# The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. MVC User Profile Advice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

My scenario is that I want to list all the user logins and their roles on a sort of admin page, where only admin users will be able to access

In my UserProfile model, there is no field for Role as I am using the SimpleMembershipProvider, so I've chosen to tackle this with a ViewModel that looks as follows:

```
Imports WebMatrix.WebData

Public Class vmUserProfile

    Public Property UserId As Integer
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Role As String


End Class
```

Thereafter, in my controller where I am creating my list of this ViewModel, the code looks as follows:

```
 Public Function GetListOfUsers() As ActionResult
    Dim users = From e In db.UserProfile
                 Select New vmUserProfile With {.UserId = e.UserId, _
                                                .Username = e.UserName, _
                                                .Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0) _
                                               }

    Return PartialView("Partial/_UserList", users.ToList.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Username))
End Function
```

The part that I'm having an issue with is `.Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)` which I'm quite aware LINQ to Entities is not happy with because of the array.

I've looked at other examples and seen that others have solved this problem by putting the relevant array index into a separate variable but for the life of me I cannot see how to apply that to my current dilemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty rubbish with VB, and am used to C#. I also tend to use the lambda syntax for linq rather than the query syntax.

But I'll give it a go!

I've seen this error my self a few times, and I'm pretty sure it crops up when you call a method within a linq to entities statement that it can't translate to SQL. In your case `Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)` can't be translated to SQL.

I'm afraid that I can't write VB or linq in query syntax, but here is my solution in C# and lambda syntax. This is what you have now:

```
var users = 
    db.UserProfile
        .Select(e => new vmUserProfile()
        {
            UserId = e.UserID,
            Username = e.Username,
            Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)
        })
```

If you change it to this it should work:

```
var users = 
    db.UserProfile
        .Select(e => new
        {
            e.UserID,
            e.Username
        })
        .ToList()
        .Select(e => new vmUserProfile()
        {
            UserId = e.UserID,
            Username = e.Username,
            Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)
        })
```

The key difference here is that I am pulling a list of anonymous objects containing the `UserID` and `Username` into memory by calling `ToList()` before selecting the values into a new `vmUserProfile` and calling `Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)

**EDIT**

Thought I'd have a stab at a VB version!

```
Dim users = 
    From u In (
        From e In db.UserProfile 
        Select New With 
        { 
            e.UserId, 
            e.UserName 
        }
    ).ToList
    Select New vmUserProfile With 
    { 
        .UserId = e.UserId, 
        .Username = e.UserName, 
        .Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0) 
    }
```

Comment: Just converted that into VB and that seems to have solved my issue. Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh excellent! wasn't entirely confident I could read VB very effectively either! Was my attempt in VB in my edit any good?

Comment: Mine was 

    `Dim users = db.UserProfile.Select(Function(e) New With {
        e.UserId,
        e.UserName
        }).ToList().Select(Function(e) New vmUserProfile() With {
            .UserId = e.UserId,
            .Username = e.UserName,
        .Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(e.UserName)(0)
        })`

Although I'm pretty sure the formatting is wrong and I can't portray it properly in the comments anyway :). But the only thing I saw wrong in yours is that the select into `vmUserProfile` requires a period before each property eg. `.UserId = e.UserId` etc

Comment: oh really? I tested it in linqpad and it seemed to work, but that was with anonymous objects. I have updated with the "periods" (full stops to me!) I hope i put them in the correct place

Comment: I'm just going based off of the syntax highlighting that Visual Studio was giving me, but now I know about LINQPad, fancy that! The fullstops are in the correct places in your edit. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: No problem! Linqpad is awesome! I rarely have to write SQL any more! But it also shows you the SQL your linq query translates into which I find really useful as it stops me from writing seemingly simple linq queries that generate huge (and multiple) SQL queries. It's well worth paying for the premium license to get the intellisense style auto completion too